# Is it computationally more intensive to assign value to a variable or repeat a simple operation?

Tags: python, c, memory-management, computation

Now i may be nitpicking here but i wanted to know which is computationally more efficient over a large number of iterations (assuming no restrictions on memory) purely in terms of time taken to run the overall programme.
i am asking mainly in terms of two languages python and c, since these are the two i use most.
for e.g. in c, something like:

```
int count, sum = 0, 0;
while (count < 99999){
    if (((pow(count, 2))/10)%10 == 4) {// just some random operation
        sum += pow(count, 2);
        }
    count++;
    }
```

or

```
int count, sum, temp = 0, 0, 0;
while (count < 99999){
    temp = pow(count, 2)
    if (((temp/10)%10 == 4) {// just some random operation
        sum += temp;
        }
    count++;
    }
```

In python something like

```
for i in range (99999):
    n = len(str(i))
    print "length of string", str(i), "is", n
```

or

```
for i in range (99999):
    temp = str(i)
    n = len(temp)
    print "length of string:, temp, "is", n
```

Now these are just random operations i thought on the fly, my main question is whether it is better create a new variable or just repeat the operation. i know the computing power required will change as `i`, `count` increases but just generalizing for a large number of iterations which is better.

Comment: It depends: a lot. Typically, the answer is doing the operation again is more expensive, but for some things (like bitwise operations in C for byteswapping, or other tasks) the operation can be cheaper. Typically, I would create the new variable if you're worried about performance and do the operation once. If you really need to know, the only long term answer is profile your code.

Comment: Luckily Python has a `timeit` module answering exactly that question.

Comment: Assuming that the C compiler doesn't know that pow() is free of side effects, it won't be able to optimise out the second call. From the point of view of the compiler the two pieces of code have different behaviour. Imagine that pow() itself called printf(); the first example would occasionally print two lines, the second example would not. We know that pow() is free of side effects, so we have to program accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested both your codes in python with `timeit`, and the result was `1.0221271729969885` seconds for the first option, `1.0154028950055363` for the second option

I have done this test only with one iteration on each example and as you can see, they are extremely close to each other, too close to be reliable after only one iteration. If you want to learn more though, I suggest you do these tests yourself with `timeit`

However, the action you took here is to replace a variable assignment to `temp` with **2** calls for `str(i)`, not one, and it can of course vary wildly for other functions that are more or less complicated and time consuming than `str` is

Answer (score 0):

Caching does improve performance and readability of the code most of the time. There may be corner cases for some super fast operations, however I'd say the type of code used in second examples would always be better.

Cached value will most probably be stored in register, hence the one mov will be involved. According to [this document](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) there are not so many cheaper operations.

As for readability consider bigger function calls with more arguments, while reviewing code it will require more brainwork to check that calls are the same, moreover if function changes it may introduce bugs where one call has been modified and the other one has been forgotten (true mostly for Python).

All in all it should be readability driving your choices in such cases rather than performance gains. Unless profiler points at this piece of code.